# Annotation in MapKit Map is transparent

Tags: ios, mapkit

When I place a Pin into a visible Map, I can't set a background color. The text keeps to be on top of a transparent background. If I show a modal View on top of the MapView and dismiss it again, the MapView show the white background without changing anything with the Map code.

Did someone has similar effects learned and has a solution?

[image: transparent background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT and it was of course ME.

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I was not careful and placed this line of code two times in the same cell declaration:

```
Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Silly me, but this causes the transparent background since - I think - two cells were initialized which lead to this.